# Should we create a new "acoustics" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There's no tag for noise or engine-noise, sound, acoustics, or any related thing I could find. I'm wondering if anyone else has come across a lot of questions involving these things, and if there should be a generic acoustics tag.

Comment: There's a tag for "noise" with 18 questions.

Comment: @fooot odd it didn't come up when i typed in "noise" on my last question.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't seen a lot of questions coming across our stack that have to do mainly with acoustics.  You will a few, here and there, that deal with "noise" (like fooot said in his comment), mainly from engines and a couple from sonic booms.

But there aren't many Aviation.SE users that are asking really advanced questions about sound (like surface reflectivity, dampening, harmonic waves, etc etc).  In fact, if they were I'd almost recommend moving the questions over to Phyics.SE.

Though, I will say, if we start seeing a lot of those questions I think a tag would be in order.

Comment: Well that begs a similar question, because questions about lift, drag, and thrust are okay here? Which could also go on Physics.SE. Just because acoustics are rarer (read: less popular) doesn't make it any less applicable to aviation.

Comment: @DrZ214 Mmmm, you may have a point there.  I think the reason I say what I say is I don't feel like acoustics relates too much to how a plane actually operates, where as lift, drag and thrust are integral to what makes a plane a plane.  All of that being said, I've been wrong before (many times even).  Though I think my last sentence is really were most of my sentiment lies...